# ¿Cómo agregar SSL para redirigir a HTTPS instancia de EC2 usando GoDaddy DNS?

Tags: aws, dns, ec2, godaddy

Tengo un sitio ya montado en una instancia de EC2, el sitio es accesible desde la IP de la instancia.

Realicé una modificación de DNS en GoDaddy, agregué un registro A apuntando a la IP de la instancia. Esto hizo que el sitio fuera accesible desde el dominio, pero usando HTTP.

He estado investigando acerca de la creación de un balanceador de carga, pero encuentro muchos sitios donde usan Route53, pero no lo puedo usar porque GoDaddy tiene mis DNS y no debo de cambiar los NS del dominio.

No sé si puedo usar el certificate manager de AWS o debo de comprar uno en GoDaddy. Y hacer configuraciones internas en mi instancia con Ubuntu.

En resumen, busco redirigir el HTTP a HTTPS, configurando la instancia de EC2 y/o los DNS de GoDaddy, sin tocar los nameservers.

Comment: Se puede configurar algo en el EC2 que resuelva eso (un nginx?) y poner el certificado allá. Se puede poner algo intermedio. Route53 implica que el DNS esté en AWS y no en GoDaddy.

Comment: Si usas Linux porque no usas letsencrypt y te ahorras todo el estres

Comment: Tal vez quiera seguir paso a paso este tutorial en goDaddy de [How to enable HTTPS on your server](https://www.godaddy.com/garage/enable-https-server/). Si tienes una ip dedicada para tu servidor, esté donde esté, este tutorial te va a funcionar perfecto.

Comment: @JosueVargas Let's encrypt me mostró Certbot. Es demasiado fácil y rápido configurarlo con Certbot. No tardé ni 2 minutos